# How do create a HTML scraper in PHP and get it working properly?

Tags: php, mysql, scraper

Please HELP! :(

I am looking to develop a PHP Script to do the following:

- Scrap a remote HTML page and extract selected data (e.g. particular table/div)
- Use extracted data and save it into a Database (e.g. MySql)

Anyone can help out?

Thanks and appreciate your soonest feedback.

Comment: In what way would this be a bad idea?

Comment: Has been answered many times before: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scrape+HTML+php

Comment: @krike - relying on data that can change without warning. you would rather have a contract with the data provider, use xml/json output.

Comment: yes but if the data provider does not offer that option there is no other choice then scrapping html dom

Answer (score 7):

Use [cUrl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to retreive page.

Use [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to find data you need.

Eventually [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) to convert fetched data to your database character set.

And just mysql connection and simple queries to store data (don't forget to escape).

Comment: lol you were faster in replying :d

Answer (score 3):

Here's some code that does the job:

```
// Fetch page
$file = fopen($url, "r"); 

$data = '';
while (!feof($file)) {
// Extract the data from the file / url
$data .= fgets($file, 1024);
}

$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadHtml($data);

// XPath lets you search DOM documents easily
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodelist = $xpath->query('//table[class=mytable]');
```

This will fetch a node list, which you can iterate over, for any tables with the class 'mytable'

Take a look at [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

Answer (score 0):

What a coincidence, recently i have worked on similar project.
My final solution was

1. cUrl to fetch contents from urls
2. Simple HTML DOM Parser to get required required part of html using jquery like selectors.

I strongly recommend both of them.